# Post-hoc analysis when variable effect is non-significant

Tags: statistical-significance, repeated-measures, nonparametric, post-hoc

In a dataset with 3 related measurements for each case, I ran a Friedman test, and found no significant effect.

Is it appropriate to now run (and report) pairwise tests, as I had planned initially?

On one hand, the existence of these pairwise effects may convey important information (e.g. there's a difference between having one day of learning or having none, but no difference between having one day or one week.)

But, more fundamentally, if the main effect isn't there, shouldn't that be the end of the story as far as reporting this particular study?